# Airflow 2.2.0 Install Error: package versions have conflicting dependencies cattrs

Tags: failed-installation, airflow-2.x

I am getting below error while trying to follow the installation steps at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html

```
ERROR: Cannot install apache-airflow[celery]==2.2.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    apache-airflow[celery] 2.2.0 depends on cattrs<1.7.0 and ~=1.1; python_version > "3.6"
    The user requested (constraint) cattrs==1.0.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

Answer (score 4):

I made a copy of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.0/constraints-3.6.txt file in my present working directory locally and changed the "cattrs==1.0.0" to "cattrs==1.1.0"

and then used below command for installation

```
pip3 install --force-reinstall "apache-airflow[celery]==2.2.0" --constraint constraints.txt
```

Edit: I later realized that issue was due to using wrong constraints file version. I had Python 3.8 installed on my machine while I was using constraints-3.6.txt instead of constraints-3.8.txt

Correct command should be as below:

```
pip3 install "apache-airflow[celery]==2.2.0" --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-${AIRFLOW_VERSION}/constraints-${PYTHON_VERSION}.txt"
```